# Is the source validator (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.sourcevalidation) related with the editor or just with the content-type?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Currently I have source validator(org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.sourcevalidation) to check the html source:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.sourcevalidation">
    <validator
        scope="total"
        class="com.test.HtmlValidator"
        id="com.test.HtmlValidator.total">
        <contentTypeIdentifier
            id="org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource">
            <partitionType id="org.eclipse.wst.html.HTML_DEFAULT"/>
            <partitionType id="org.eclipse.wst.html.HTML_DECLARATION"/>
            <partitionType id="org.eclipse.wst.html.HTML_COMMENT"/>
        </contentTypeIdentifier>
    </validator>
```

The source validator works as expected with the default html editor (org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource.source) but if I open the same files with the Eclipse Generic Editor (org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.GenericEditor, Eclipse Wild Web Developer uses it to open all the web development files) the source validator does not work.

Until I know the source validator works directly with the content type not with the editor, my question here is what should I do to make the validator work with both editors?

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/sse/tutorials/source-validation.html) seems to be saying it is only available in editors based on the Eclipse WTP Structured Source Editor

Comment: I have found the way to add the validator to the org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.GenericEditor using the org.eclipse.wst.validation.validatorV2 but the only problem is that validatorV2 is triggered manually only, @greg-449 do you know what is the way to configure the validatorV2 to defect the files changes like the sse.ui.sourcevalidation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I have found a workaround using the org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.documentSetup extension point, this extension point executes the method IDocumentSetupParticipant.setup(IDocument document), the advantage of this extension point is that it is independent of the editor. org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.documentSetup executes when a file with certain content type is open using any editor.

```
<extension
       point="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.documentSetup">
   <participant
      class="setup.HTMLDocumentSetup"
      contentTypeId="org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource">
    </participant>
 </extension>
```

In IDocumentSetupParticipant.setup we can register a IDocumentListener, this interface defines 2 methods:

1. documentAboutToBeChanged
2. documentChanged

If we use documentChanged, every time that the user types something in the editor the method will executed.